# How to use multiline Postgres in Terraform with EOF

Tags: postgresql, terraform

I have the following Terraform `kubernetes_job` code:

```
resource "kubernetes_job" "user" {
  metadata {
    name      = "create-user"
  }
  spec {
    template {
      metadata {}
      spec {
        container {
          name    = "test"
          command = ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
          args = [<<-EOF
            PGPASSWORD=<password> psql -h <host> -U <user> -d <db>
            CREATE ROLE test WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'test123';
            GRANT readonly_role TO test;
          EOF
          ]
        }
        restart_policy = "Never"
      }
    }
    backoff_limit = 1
    completions   = 1
  }

}
```

Note the `args` command above. I am trying to pass in 2 Postgres commands in via `EOF` as an argument, however I am getting the errors:

> /bin/sh: 2: CREATE: not found

> /bin/sh: 3: GRANT: not found

Is this possible to pass in Postgres commands via `EOF` like this?

Comment: This needs to be a list of strings, so it will not work anyway without quotation marks. It also won't work with heredoc syntax. You are expecting that the first command will drop you into psql shell and you would run the subsequent two commands there? If so, I don't think this can work even if the arguments were defined properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-c` option to a typical Unix-style shell interprets its argument as if it were the contents of a shell script file. In your case, that would be as if you had written the following into a file and then executed it with the shell:

```
PGPASSWORD=<password> psql -h <host> -U <user> -d <db>
CREATE ROLE test WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'test123';
GRANT readonly_role TO test;
```

Your shell understands how to run the first line as a shell command, running the `psql` program and passing it the given arguments.

The remaining lines seem to be commands that the `psql` command *itself* ought to consume, but this script doesn't do anything to cause those lines to be passed in to `psql`, and so instead your shell tried to interpret them as more shell commands.

To make this work you'd need to choose some mechanism to tell your shell to pass the two following lines to `psql`.

I'm not really familiar with this `psql` command in particular but from context I'm inferring that it's [the PosgreSQL command line tool](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html), and its documentation suggests two possible ways to make this work which I'm going to describe below but I cannot actually test myself because I don't have a Postgres server to test against.

---

The first approach is to notice that `psql` has its *own* `-c` argument which has a similar meaning to the one for your shell but provides a series of SQL commands to run instead of a series of shell commands.

One way to use that would be to skip using the shell entirely and make your container instead just run the `psql` command directly, which I think would look like this:

```
        container {
          name    = "test"
          command = [
            "/usr/bin/psql",
            "-h", "<host>",
            "-U", "<user>",
            "-d", "<db>",
            "-c", <<-EOF
              CREATE ROLE test WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'test123';
              GRANT readonly_role TO test;
            EOF
          ]
        }
```

(I'm not entirely sure what the difference is between `command` and `args` here, since both of them seem to be arrays of arguments to use to execute a program. I just combined them together because it seemed simpler this way, but if that doesn't work then it might be worth trying splitting it back into `command` and `args` again, in which case the `<<-EOF` sequence would go in `args` the same way as you had it in your example but now containing only SQL commands, not any shell commands.)

---

The second approach is to notice that the `psql` command apparently expects to receive commands on its [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)) filehandle, and so to change your shell script to pass the SQL commands into there so that the `psql` command can read them.

Terraform's "heredoc" syntax (the `<<EOF` thing you are using) is actually inspired by a similar feature within a Unix shell which causes some content to be sent to a command's standard input filehandle, and so you can use a similar syntax *inside* your shell script. Although the two look similar, the outer one is being handled by Terraform and the inner one is being handled by the shell.

```
        container {
          name    = "test"
          command = ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
          args = [<<-EOF
            PGPASSWORD=<password> psql -h <host> -U <user> -d <db> <<EOS
              CREATE ROLE test WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'test123';
              GRANT readonly_role TO test;
            EOS
          EOF
          ]
        }
```

This can work because the "EOF" sequence that you're using is really just an arbitrary name used to match up with the closing marker. By choosing a different name for the shell's `<<` sequence -- `EOS` in this case -- we can make sure that the two don't conflict: the `EOS` marks the end of the shell's`<<EOS` and the `EOF` marks the end of Terraform's `<<-EOF`.

Comment: The second example  worked for me! Note: I had some additional Postgres commands in there that I did not include in the example above, so I had to escape each one, e.g., I had `DO \$\$` at the beginning which I had to escape